# Sliding a view controller from bottom with a Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, gesture

I have a question (Objective-C related).

I want to create a sliding from bottom ViewController on top of the Root Map View Controller by a click on the annotation.

1) After a click on the annotation it should slide from bottom and show 10% of the height;
2) after an upward swipe gesture - it should show up to 100% if the user drags it upwards fully;
3) on the downward gesture user should be able to decrease its visible height to 10% again;
4) on the MapView click the bottom ViewController should hide.

I'm including the Visual scheme of the process implementation.

[image]

Any ideas are very very appreciated!

Comment: you want to add UIView or UIViewController there?

Comment: at a time you can push only UIViewController on navigation bar

Comment: check my answer i have edited.

Comment: yes, checking. this example would require implementation before i can truly say if it fits or not. thank you for the insight

Comment: Hey David Robertson,I came across a similar requirement what you have,did you find any proper solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

check this demo

[NHSlidingController](https://github.com/nilsou/NHSlidingController)

[PanningViewController](https://github.com/emilylaguna/PanningViewController)

Comment: Thank you. Just checked. It Slides from the left, but i'm looking for an example with the controller sliding from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to write your own segue animation to transition between ViewControllers. Just make a custom UIStoryboardSegue, and override its perform method. Here is a snippet to start with:

```
@interface HorizontalSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@property CGPoint originatingPoint;

@end


@implementation VerticalSegue

- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    NSArray* windowArray = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
    if (windowArray.count > 0) {
        UIWindow* appWindow = [windowArray lastObject];
        [appWindow insertSubview:destinationViewController.view aboveSubview:sourceViewController.view];
    }
    else
        [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

    // Store original centre point of the destination view
    CGPoint originalCenter = destinationViewController.view.center;

    // Set center to start point of the button
    destinationViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.originatingPoint.x, self.originatingPoint.y*3);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         destinationViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]; // present VC
                     }];
}

@end
```

Using this you can easily make custom animations. I am not totally sure if the part with adding the ViewController to the window is correct, but this is something that you could try and check/correct yourself.

Another way of animating segues is using CATransition:

```
-(void)perform
{
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

    [destinationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely check that code out. Still working around the issue